# Application Insights - is it right to use href as "View page name"?

Tags: javascript, azure-application-insights

As I know, Application Insights uses page title as View page name. But my application has simillar page title for all pages. And that is why I always get only one pageview and can`t create propper userflow graph, because AI displays, that user visit only one page all the time.
[User flow graph with one pageview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUchN.png)

That is why I added this TelemetryInitializer on client side to track pageview by href but I am not shure if it is a right approach.

```
const telemetryInitializer = envelope => {
            envelope.baseData.name = window.location.href;
        };

appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(telemetryInitializer);
```

Maybe Azure Team has any other way to do it without changing page title?

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to approach this.  Application Insights [User Flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-flows) starts from a page view, custom event, or exception that you specify.  In my example below, I've used [custom events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics).  A custom event in JavaScript might look like this:

```
appInsights.trackEvent({name:"SuccessfulUserLogin"});
```

(For detailed instructions on how to log custom events, see the documentation on [TrackEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackevent).)

Here I've used the custom event "SuccessfulUserLogin" as the Initial Event in Application Insights to create a User Flows graph:

[image: Application Insights User Flows settings]

That in turn allowed me to track the user flow using the custom events that I specified on other pages (tracking the custom event "VisitedUserForum" on the user forum page and "VisitedFeedbackForum" on the feedback forum page even if both pages were named "forums"):

[image: Application Insights User Flow based on custom events]